# Converting Blob to text in Python using Speechrecognition

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, speech-recognition

I am developing voice chatbot using rasa framework. Where voice is recorded through HTML5's mediaRecorder
and sent as a Form data in Flask web service.

```
@app.route('api/stt',methods = ['POST'])  
def STT():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["audioBlob"]    
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with open("audio.wav", "wb") as aud:
            aud_stream = file.read()
            aud.write(aud_stream )
#         with sr.Microphone() as source:
#             print("Say something!")
            audio = r.listen(aud)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                text = "Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio"
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                text = "Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e)
            return text
```

Code from html side

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                console.log(audioBlob)
                var myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "audio/wave");
                var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    body: audioBlob,
                    redirect: 'follow'
                };

                // call the STT api
                fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/stt", requestOptions)
```

I want to audio blob direct convert to text.

This my code is not working. I have less experience in python side. Please help me out on this. With explanation will highly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

first try adding multipart in the client side, then try to use form data on the client side , then on the backend look for `byteencorder` to convert the file then pass it to the speech library

**Method 2**

Instead of `request.file['audioBlob']` use `request.file`